# Insert rows in a table based on number of rows from another worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to insert a specific number of rows into a table based on criteria of number of rows from another worksheet. What I want to do is insert the rows below the top line in the table. I am trying all sorts of code but to no avail, this is what I have and some code at the bottom that I have tried.

```
'Counts number of rows 
Int_rows = Range("m7:y7").End(xlDown).Row - 6
Windows("Sheet2").Activate
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table").Resize (Int_rows), (0)
'ActiveSheet.ListObjects("APR_Table").ListRows.Add (2)
'Range("Table").Resize(Int_Rows).EntireRow.Insert
```

Answer (score 1):

Please consider using the following code:

```
Sub AddRows()
    Dim Int_rows As Integer
    Int_rows = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("m7:y7").End(xlDown).Row - 6

    Sheets("Sheet2").Rows("2:" & (Int_rows + 1)).Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
End Sub
```

Regards,

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, you can only insert ListRows one at a time through VBA.

The following will work.

```
Int_rows = Range("m7:y7").End(xlDown).Row - 6

Dim LO as ListObject
Set LO = Worksheets("Sheet2").ListObjects("Table")

For x = 1 to Int_rows
     LO.ListRows.Add , AlwaysInsert:=True
     x = x +1
Next
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this works perfectly!! Very much appreciated

Comment: @BarryMaskell - Glad it worked. Please mark as answered (green check mark on upper left of answer) so others benefit going forward.